# How can I map a custom image to a polygon in a game?

Tags: java

I'm trying to basically remake Asteroids in java, but I'm going to use a bald eagle as a ship that shoots down Soviet flags. Right now, my bald eagle image is a square with a white outline around the eagle. I would like to remove this, is there any way to map this in a one-to-one fashion to a polygon of sorts?

Here's my code, though I don't know exactly how this will help anything:

```
 public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GameTest t = new GameTest();
}

public static class GameTest extends JFrame {

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;

    public GameTest() throws IOException {
        super("Deep Fried Freedom");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        add(gamePanel);
        center(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void center(JFrame frame) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Point center = ge.getCenterPoint();

        int w = frame.getWidth();
        int h = frame.getHeight();

        int x = center.x - w / 2, y = center.y - h / 2;
        frame.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        frame.validate();
    }//end of center method  
}
}


public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
public static BufferedImage baldEagleImage;

public GamePanel() throws IOException {
    super();
    baldEagleImage = ImageIO.read(new File("baldeagleimage.jpg"));
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);// set color black
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // paint background
    g.drawImage(baldEagleImage, 350, 175, null);//paint the launcher
}//end paintComponent method
}//end GamePanel class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways that you can achieve this effect. Your best bet would be to use the alpha channel of your image. Just open your image in an image editing tool such as Gimp. In this set the background of your image to transparent around your image.

Another option (which is not the best) but fulfils your request is to use a paint stroke in Java2D. Have a look at using the java2d clipping feature. You can get a tutorial on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will have a Java object that represents the ship, and it has x and y coordinates called something like centerX and centerY.  That gives you the center of the ship on your screen within the bounds of the viewable area.  You modify these values when you want the ship to move up and down, and you g.drawImage the image you want to use at these coordinates as well (plus any offsets as needed to make the image appear centered to your liking).

A common method is to have a thread started upon initialization, and in that thread is a while(true) block that does an update() method on all objects that need to be updated, and then a Thread.sleep(17) that mimics a framerate of about 60 frames per second.  In this method, your ship has its X and Y coords updated and then the image drawn at that location every 17 milliseconds, and that's how you get a ship (and any other object for that matter) to appear like they are moving around on the screen.